# Non-singleton service in Standalone component

Tags: angular

Is it possible to create a non-singleton service in standalone component. so every instance of this component will use its own instance of this service?

i've tried to list the service in providers list of the component but got an null injector error.

Comment: Why you want to do something like that? In that case is better to have a class that you instantiate in the controller constructor so you will have an instance for each component.

Answer (score 3):

Just create `@Injectable()` class for your service, and provide it to standalone component:

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  ...
}
```

and the component usage example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  providers: [TestService],
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private test: TestService) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanx all. i'm using an inject function instead of a usual constructor declaration, so @Self was not an option, the second solution works great my mistake was that i've provided the service in parent (inherited) component which i use as a base for the standalone component i've moved the providers list to the extended component and now it works as expected :-) Thank you for all the answers

Comment: You can even use `@Self` in `inject` function like this: `private testService = inject(TestService, { self: true })`

Answer (score 0):

To do this, pass your service in the providers list and use `@Self` to ensure you're using your own instance

```
class Service {
  value = Math.random();
}


@Component({
   selector: 'child', 
   standalone: true, 
   template: '<div>{{service.value}}</div>', 
   providers: [Service]
})
class ChildComponent{
  constructor(@Self() protected service:Service) {}
}
```

By using [`@Self`](https://angular.io/api/core/Self) you'll get a runtime verification that the instance is only your own (for the component) even if the service is `providedIn:'root'`.