# angualr 16 standalone imports NgxPermissionsModule

Tags: angular

I have a problem with angular 16 standalone component and NgxPermissions like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxPermissionsModule, NgxPermissionsService } from 'ngx-permissions';

@Component({
  selector: 'pd-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgxPermissionsModule],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  private permissionsService: NgxPermissionsService;

  ngOnInit() {
    const perm = ['ADMIN', 'EDITOR'];

    this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(perm);
  }
}
```

I [created a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-smvykq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) with this error:

Error: R3InjectorError(Standalone[AppComponent])[NgxPermissionsService -> NgxPermissionsService -> NgxPermissionsService]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for NgxPermissionsService!

how do you import modules into a standalone?
I can't find any documentation about it (obviously if I used modules it works correctly)

Comment: I think this will solve your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75922771/non-singleton-service-in-standalone-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the provider to the environment injector using `importProvidersFrom` :

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [importProvidersFrom(NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot())],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```